# Android - Show/Hide system bar on 4.2.2 (Nexus 10)

Tags: android, root, android-4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-10

I got issue with Nexus 10 - 4.2.2. I was testing code below on Galaxy Tab 10.1 with 4.0.4 and it was working fine:

```
try 
{
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","startservice","-n","com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"});
    proc.waitFor();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try
{
    //REQUIRES ROOT
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui"}); //WAS 79
    proc.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But on Nexus 10 system bar won't show after, just hide.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying :S please work on the gramar (someone?)

Comment: never mind I've just find the solution.

Comment: @goodm I am facing the same issue, can you update the code, how you overcome the issue..

Comment: @kumarsu my code is below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show and hide the system bar and notification bar on 4.2.2 and others:

Hide:

```
    try
    {
        String command;
        command = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui";
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command }, envp);
        proc.waitFor();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Show:

```
    try 
    {
         String command;
         command = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService";
         Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command }, envp);
         proc.waitFor();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Does this require Root?

Comment: How is envp initialized?  Can the version without envp be used?

Comment: Are there any permissions we need to add to the manifest ? Also do we need to install this APK in the system directory to work ? I am trying this code out on kitkat on a rooted device and it does not seem to work. I just get a IOException

Comment: Yes, this requires root.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should not use system calls via `Runtime.exec()` to get that result.
You should look at the code in `FullscreenActivity` template (sources are placed in `<android-sdk-folder>/tools/templates/activities/FullscreenActivity/root`): that is a full working example showing how to show/hide system bars (both top and bottom one) programmatically, and it even supports animations for API 13+.

Comment: Once updated, if you use Eclipse+ADT, you can use template wizard to generate that sample activity in your Android project: menu `File>New>Android>Android Object>Fullscreen Activity`

Comment: Don't worry this step I can handle ;)

Comment: Sorry, maybe a little overeager, I know :)

Comment: Only one disadvantage of using the temple is this that you have to override the volume buttons cause after every click bottom system bar come back and whatever you do, after long press on power, bottom bar came back. So in the end probably I will have to use my method, because this will be a kiosk app so I need to limit the user as much is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by goodm works fine, but most of us are not aware about **envp**

So here is full code:

**HIDE**

```
try
{
    String command;
    command = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui";

    ArrayList<String> envlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        envlist.add(envName + "=" + env.get(envName));
    }
    String[] envp = (String[]) envlist.toArray(new String[0]);
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command }, envp);
    proc.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You can use similar for show.