# How get real height of system and navigation bars when they are hidden

Tags: java, android

I want get real (!) status or height of both (system and navigation) bars on Android device with root when they bars are hidden.

Bars hidden by superuser commands: [Android - Show/Hide system bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095998/android-show-hide-system-bar-on-4-2-2-nexus-10).

I try get height of system and navigation bars by [System bar size on android tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718800/1665964):

```
// status bar (at the top of the screen on a Nexus device) 
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}

// navigation bar (at the bottom of the screen on a Nexus device)
public static int getNavigationBarHeight(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this method return virtual height: status bar - 38 px, navigation bar - 72 px on my device.

I need get this sizes only when bars really showed on screen. And return 0 in my case with hidden bars.

Is it possible get real height?

Also may be is possible get status system and navigation bars: hidden or shown?